# How to wait for cookie before setting authContext and login state. React, Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, token

I have a createUser function that sends an axios req to express and takes some time to finish creating a firebase authenticated user, create a token and send token back to user as a cookie.

I also have a getLoggedIn function that takes the cookie and sends it to express to get authenticated and then adjust my authContext accordingly.

My function looks like this: `await createUser(registerData ).then(() => getLoggedIn())`

My problem is that getLoggedIn() is being called early, before the createUser is done sending back the cookie.  Any idea how to fix this?  Is there a way to listen for a cookie change?  I dont see other people doing that, do I have the wrong approach in general?

Thanks for any help.

New User Form

```
 const { getLoggedIn, loggedIn } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const register = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
     const registerData = {
      email,
      password,
      passwordVerify,
    };
    try {
      await createUser(registerData).then(() => getLoggedIn());
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }};
```

CreateUser

```
export const createUser = async (props) => {
      console.log("New User Creation Initiated", props);
      const { email, password, passwordVerify } = props;
      let userObject = { tokenId: null };
    
      try {
        await firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(({ user }) => {
            console.log("createUserWithEmailAndPassword", user);
            user
              .getIdToken()
              .then((tokenId) => {
                userObject = { tokenId: tokenId };
                axios.post(`${domain}/auth`, userObject);
              })
              .catch((err) => console.log("new user error", err));
           })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("createUser Error", err);
          });
        return;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("New User Creation Error: ", err);
      }
    };
```

AuthContext

```
const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  console.log("AuthContextProvider Initiated");

  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(null);

  const getLoggedIn = async () => {
    console.log("getLoggedIn Initiated");
    let validatedUser = await axios.get(`${domain}/auth/loggedIn`);
    console.log("AuthContextProvider validatedUser", validatedUser);
    setLoggedIn(validatedUser.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLoggedIn();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, getLoggedIn }}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
 };
```

Express

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("---User signup initiated---");

  try {
    const { tokenId } = req.body;
    console.log("tokenId passed from frontend: ", tokenId);
    admin
      .auth()
      .verifyIdToken(tokenId)
      .then((decodedToken) => {
        const { email, uid } = decodedToken;
        console.log("Fetched UID: ", uid);
        console.log("Fetched email: ", email);
        const Users = db.collection("users");
        Users.doc(`${uid}`).set({
          email: email,
          posts: [],
        });
        console.log("---jwt signing initiated---");

        const token = jwt.sign(
          {
            user: { email, uid },
          },
          process.env.JWT_SECRET
        );
        console.log("token log: ", token);

        return res
          .cookie("token", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: true,
          })
          .send();
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

router.get("/loggedIn", (req, res) => {
  console.log("login validation initiated");
  try {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    if (!token) {
      console.log("no token cookie");
      return res.json(null);
    }

     const validatedUser = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    console.log("Token cookie: ", validatedUser);

    res.json(validatedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("loggedIn", err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onAuthStateChanged like this in your AuthContext.

```
const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  console.log("AuthContextProvider Initiated");

  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(null);

  const getLoggedIn = async () => {
    console.log("getLoggedIn Initiated");
    let validatedUser = await axios.get(`${domain}/auth/loggedIn`);
    console.log("AuthContextProvider validatedUser", validatedUser);
    setLoggedIn(validatedUser.data);
  };
  
  const handleAuthStateChanged = user => {
    if(user) { //user login
      getLoggedIn()
    } else { //user logout
      setLoggedIn(null)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      handleAuthStateChanged(user)
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, []);
  

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, getLoggedIn }}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately the problem persists.  All that happens now is that getLoggedIn() fires twice, both times with a null response.  There is no req.cookies.token for my "/loggedIn" express route to use.

Answer (score 0):

In my createUser function I moved my axios call and returned it outside of the firebase.auth() sequence of promises. Seems to work now.

```
export const createUser = async (props) => {
  console.log("New User Creation Initiated", props);
  const { email, password, passwordVerify } = props;
  let userObject = { tokenId: null };

  try {
    await firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(({ user }) => {
        console.log("createUserWithEmailAndPassword", user);
        user
          .getIdToken()
          .then((tokenId) => {
            userObject = { tokenId: tokenId };
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log("new user error", err));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("createUser Error", err);
      });
    return axios.post(`${domain}/auth`, userObject);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("New User Creation Error: ", err);
  }
};
```